# Protect specific range by getting last row containing data with possible empty rows in between

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to protect a specific range until the last row, but after trying to consider the possibility of having empty rows in the way, I couldn't get the expected result.

In my example: I'm trying to protect a range of A:D and since the last row containing data is C24, the script should protect **A2:D24**. Column F (and anything else) is ignored in my script.

**Screenshot**:

[image]

I'm getting the following error: **Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1**

for line 30 corresponding to `var rangeToProtect = ss.getRange(2,1,(lr-1), 4);`

**My script:**

```
function getLastRow(sheet,rangeString) {

  var rng = sheet.getRange(rangeString).getValues();
  var lrIndex;

  for(var i = rng.length-1;i>=0;i--){

    lrIndex = i;

    if(!rng[i].every(function(c){ return c == ""; })){

      break;

  }
  }

  var lr = lrIndex + 1

  Logger.log(lr);

}


function protectData(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "EEE d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss")
  var lr = getLastRow(ss,"A2:D");
  var rangeToProtect = ss.getRange(2,1,(lr-1), 4);
  var protection = rangeToProtect.protect().setDescription(curDate);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());

  }
```

**// Function edited with suggestions:**

```
function protectImportedData(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+3", "EEE d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss")

  var Direction = SpreadsheetApp.Direction;
  var aLast =ss.getRange("A1:D"+(ss.getLastRow()+1)).getNextDataCell(Direction.UP).getRow();

  var rangeToProtect = ss.getRange(2,1,(aLast-1), 4);
  var protection = rangeToProtect.protect().setDescription(curDate);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());

  }
```

Comment: Function `getLastRow` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @TheMaster - Isn't that going to remove blanks that aren't at the end and then report a lower number than the actual height.

Comment: @Cooper Isn't "what" going to remove blanks....?

Comment: This `var Avals = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;`

Comment: @Cooper  OP is expected to read and test all the answers. Not just the top voted ones and choose the ones best suited for his situation. Specifically, I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51473352/) should work.

Comment: @TheMaster Sorry to bother but thanks for the info

Comment: @Cooper It's not a bother. Of the answers there, that [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51473352/) was actually the fastest of all(last i checked) and I recommend it.

Comment: Thanks to you guys, I've come across this link yesterday and I've tried some of the suggestions, but I've skipped the one you're referring to. How do I reference range from A to D in: ss.getRange("A"+(ss.getLastRow()+1)).getNextDataCell(Direction.UP).getRow();

Comment: Which I've tried before asking, but I'm getting the same error (The number of rows in the range must be at least 1)

Comment: I've added the function with the above suggestions

Comment: try `"A"+(ss.getLastRow()+1)+":D"+(ss.getLastRow()+1)`

Comment: @TheMaster, I've tried something similar and tried your suggestion as well, but it stops at row 21, in another word it's considering only column A (Protected: Sheet1!A2:D21)

Comment: @TheMaster, by the way you were right the function `getLastRow` was returning nothing, silly me!!  I'm still curious to find out how your suggestion could be implemented

Comment: Tested a bunch of things. it seems getNext* or getDataRegion* doesn't work for this. I'll undo my duplicate vote. Looping is probably the only way. If adding a `return` fixes your code, consider adding it as a answer.

Comment: Yes we'll do, thank you for pointing out the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @TheMaster for pointing out the error, the Function getLastRow was not returning anything,

The code works if we change this line:

```
var lr = lrIndex + 1
```

to:

```
return lrIndex + 1
```

Also we don't need the -1 in:

```
var rangeToProtect = ss.getRange(2,1,(lr-1), 4);
```